# bash call command on $var value

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am new to shell scripting and stepped through this quick guide:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html

which was helpful but left a lot of questions about working with variables unanswered.  My current frustration is trying to use a variable that stores a path in commands.

For example, the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

iTunesU_Source="~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/iTunes\ U/"
ls -al $iTunesU_Source

iTunesU_Source_symlink="~/Music/iTunes_U/"
ls -al $iTunesU_Source_symlink

ls -al ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/iTunes\ U/
```

Prints out:

```
ls: Media/iTunes\: No such file or directory
ls: U/: No such file or directory
ls: ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\: No such file or directory
ls: ~/Music/iTunes_U/: No such file or directory
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   7 me  staff  238 Mar  8 10:06 .
drwxr-xr-x  11 me  staff  374 Mar  8 11:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x  27 me  staff  918 Mar  8 08:44 Game Theory - Audio
drwxr-xr-x   3 me  staff  102 Mar  8 10:03 Introduction to Algorithms
drwxr-xr-x  23 me  staff  782 Mar  8 12:17 Machine Learning
drwxr-xr-x   3 me  staff  102 Mar  8 10:06 Machine Learning-Stanford
```

How do I get the command (ls/cd/etc...) to accept the value of the variable like it does for direct input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution:

```
iTunesU_Source="~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/iTunes U/"
```

Why is that? In this line:

```
iTunesU_Source="~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/iTunes\ U/"
```

You're setting the value of the variable to a quoted string. Within quotes, whitespace is already preserved. So, the contents of your variable will be, literally:

```
~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/iTunes\ U/
```

The backslashes are only needed to escape whitespace in unquoted strings, so you could have *almost* written this like:

```
iTunesU_Source=~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/iTunes\ U/
```

The difference is that in the first command, the `~` is not expanded by shell to your home directory, whereas in the second command your variable `iTunesU_Source` is assigned `/Users/username`. So in that case, your variable holds:

```
/Users/username/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/iTunes\ U/
```

Read more about quoting here:

- [Quotes - Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)
- [Quotes and escaping [Bash Hackers Wiki]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)

Comment: awesome, thanks.  For whatever reason, it still doesn't work with the full path, but the symlink i made works now that I removed the quotes.

Comment: You're welcome! What "doesn't work" about the full path? Do you get any error message?

Comment: must have been a user error.  i recreated it to try and get the error but not it is working, of course ;)

Comment: Note that this line: `ls -al $iTunesU_Source` should be `ls -al "$iTunesU_Source"` as well.